# two commas on first page

Tags: punctuation, titles

When I compile my document I get a very strange first page. It only has 2 commas and the pagenumber on it. Has anyone has this problem before or knows how to solve it? I have included a minimal example below including all packages I use. I am using Texmaker.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{courier}


\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}

\begin{document}
\title{Respect my authoritah!}, \author{Cartman, Eric}, \date{\today} 
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Remove the commas after the `\title` and the `\author` definition.

Comment: That's it. I feel quite retarded know... Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The code you have provided is not really a MWE. If you want a standard title page, then do

```
\documentclass{report}

\title{Respect my authoritah!}
\author{Cartman, Eric}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Presumably you want the title page to look different. Maybe something like

```
\documentclass{report}

\title{Respect my authoritah!}
\author{Cartman, Eric}
\date{\today}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\@title, \@author, \@date}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```